# Determine field being updated using Field Calculator and Python parser

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, arcgis-10.7

I have to updated some values in different fields and different feature classes.  The calculation is always the same.  For example if the field is called `MyValue` then the calculation would be something like

```py
!MyValue! = !MyValue! - 0.216
```

So I thought I'd save my calculator script and just run the same thing every time, however I'm still having to update the field name each time I run it.

Is there a way, in the ArcMap Field Calculator, to automatically determine the field being updated, and use the value from that field?

For example, in the code block I'd have something like

```py
def my_update():
    x = !value from the field being calculated!
    y = x - 0.216
    return y
```

and in the Expression:

```py
my_update()
```

Now I know I can pass the field name in the code, like `my_update(!MyValue!)`, but that then defeats the purpose as I'd have to update the field name every time I run it (which currently is the step that takes me the longest in this process).  So how can I get the value for `x` without having to specific the field name every time I run it, so that I can just re-use the code block and expression?

Comment: I don't think that can be achieved with field calculator. I think you could only achieve it with scripting.

Comment: Why x is not a parameter in you function? Just keep saved .call with my_update().

Comment: @FelixIP that is currently what it is, I'm trying to avoid that as I have to select and update with that field name every time I run the calculation (which is many). Just trying to speed up the manual part of the process. Each feature class has numerous fields to update and I have to scroll through them each time to select the correct ones.

Comment: @Hornbydd i believe that may be correct. I'll have to look into scripting it I guess

Comment: Yes tables with too many fields IS a pain. This is why I even wrote a script "SHOW HIDE FIELDS", it has 3 parameters: a) layout table b) table to modify c) OPTION (Show, Hide). It creates a layer from second table on the top of table of content.